# Style input and textarea across multiple columns (without divs)

Tags: html, css, forms

How can I style the following markup to allow the layout as described.

```
<form>
    <input name="one">
    <input name="two">
    <input name="three">
    <input name="four">
    <input name="five">
    <input name="six">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

To have the following layout:

```
input    input   textarea
input    input
input    input
```

Comment: Why without divs? You could use a table but using tables is deprecated since you have `display: table-cell` and similar in CSS3.

Comment: You can do it with absolute positioning of the textarea - is that something you want to use? How about JavaScript to add wrapping elements?

Comment: Divs would be the fallback, but I would prefer to keep the markup as clean as possible (if we can), absolute positioning again not ideal. Would use divs if it needed to be done with absolute.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss What is the purpose of the page? Is it for a website or for internal use? Is the form gets generated? Can you use JS to change the html or you want to use CSS only?

Comment: @NimrodShory only CSS please.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss Kindly check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `textarea as first element` then you have achieve

```css
form{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
input{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
}
textarea{
  width:33.33%;  
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input name="one">
    <input name="two">
    <input name="three">
    <input name="four">
    <input name="five">
    <input name="six">    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
form{
    position: relative;
}
input{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35%;
}
textarea{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

/*or*/
form{
    -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 4;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without absolute?

Comment: if you are willing to put the textarea after the 2nd input

Comment: I've tried the column count way, but that puts 2 inputs in the first two columns, then the textarea and last 2 inputs in the third.

Answer (score 0):

If you cn use `Bootstrap` it will be more easy

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="one">
    <input name="two">
    <input name="three">
    <input name="four">
    <input name="five">
    <input name="six">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `div` but you could do

```html
<form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="one"></td>
          <td><input name="four"></td>
          <td rowspan="3"><textarea></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="two"></td>
          <td><input name="five"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="three"></td>
          <td><input name="six"></td>
        </tr>      
      </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use table if you don't wanna use div.

```css
td{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<table>
<th>
  <td><input name="one"></td>
  <td><input name="two"></td>
  <td><input name="three"></td>
</th>

<th>
  <td><input name="four"></td>
  <td><input name="five"></td>
  <td><input name="six"></td>
</th>

<th>
  <td><textarea></textarea></td>
</th>
</table>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--Below is the inline css code with html... You can also separate it if nedded-->    
    <form style="float:left;width:100%">
        <div style="float:left;width:30%;height:auto">
            <input name="one" style="width:100%">
            <input name="two" style="width:100%">
            <input name="three" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:30%;height:auto">
            <input name="four" style="width:100%">
            <input name="five" style="width:100%">
            <input name="six" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:30%;height:auto">
            <textarea style="width:100%"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , using table

```css
textarea
{
  height:100px
  
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="one"></td>
    <td><input name="two"></td>
    <td rowspan=3><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> <input name="three"></td>  
    <td><input name="four"></td>
   </tr>
    
    <tr>
      
    <td><input name="five"></td>
   <td> <input name="six"></td>
      </tr>
    

   
    </table>
</form>
```